# How to print loading process in splash screen,

Tags: java

I am pretty new to this, I have coded a Splash screen that loads a user login and register. I am trying to have the `jlabel` print out that it is loading the classes but i can not seem to figure out how. It already loads the percent as the progress bar raises. But i want it to also print out what its loading.

The `jlabel` class is `loadingtext`

This is the main class where it loads.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpalshScreen screen = new SpalshScreen();
        NewSignin sign = new NewSignin();
        screen.setVisible(true);
        try {
            for (int row = 0; row <=100; row++) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                screen.loadingnumber.setText(Integer.toString(row)+"%");
                screen.loadingprogress.setValue(row);
                if (row == 100) {

                    screen.setVisible(false);
                    sign.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
```